# html anchor jumps to top

Tags: jquery, html, css

If you click here: http://www.ideagasms.net/index2#aciw  ...you'll be smooth-scrolled down to a section on the page titled "ACIW SERIES."

There, you'll see an accordion, and here's the problem: Click on any one of the accordion's tabs and notice how it scrolls/jumps to the top of the accordion itself.

Is there an easy way to prevent the window from jumping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `click()` event of accordion, change your script this way:

```
$(".nav_bar li").click(function() {    //  Move content horizontally
    var Tab = $(this).attr("class");
    $(".boxness").stop().animate({left : "1500px"}, 800, function() {
        $(".boxness").css("left", "-1500px").hide();
        $("#" + Tab).show().animate({left : "0px", opacity : 1.0}, 600).stop();
    });
    return false; // Give this here
});
```

Comment: This is a pure css3 accordion; the above .nav_bar belongs to a different thing.

Comment: Woah. How do you activate it? I mean, there should be a `click` function right?

Comment: It's from this awesome accordion I found here: http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/css3-target/accordionhorz.html#acc1

Comment: @Stephen Sorry buddy. This **awesome** (true) CSS only accordion relies on the `:target`, which needs to do it. So you cant exactly target it. Because, when you use `preventDefault` or `return false;`, the accordion stops working. :(

Comment: There it is, then. Use a different accordion. Thanks for letting me know about "target."

Answer (score 0):

From your click handler, you need to either do `return false` at the end or use jQuery's `preventDefault` on the event it passes to the function. Documentation on jQuery's `preventDefault` is [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).